# how to display image icon in html page embedded in email?

Tags: java, html, email

I have a page html, where i need to send an image embedded in email, but in mail icon is displayed as below:

[image]

Below is the code i have used to embed image URL in email, the image it found is in the resources folder of my project.

```html
<img src="../ScoreExcepciones/src/main/webapp/resources/theme/img/Acertum.jpg" ALIGN="right" />
```

Comment: Give absolute path in src

Comment: I think you cannot put the location like that. The picture should be hosted on some server. Even if you send the picture, most email clients would hide it because of security reasons.

Comment: if I not have a server that might otherwise be send the image.

Comment: You can upload it to some image hosting service. www.imgur.com for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the full file path to the source image?

The " ..." is referencing the internal directory that works just fine in your IDE but there's no way to fetch that when reading from email.

Comment: I use IBM Lotus Notes mail, where you could save the image

Comment: As mentioned by wazaaap, you should load it somewhere publicly accessible. imgur, photobucket, or if your organization has a public drive that anyone can get to, and that email is only being sent internally within the organization.

The shared drive is least recommended, but a quick and dirty hack if this is just internal. Otherwise, image hosting.